# Jinja does not update properly

Tags: python, html, django, templates, jinja2

I have this code in python:

```
@overviewBlueprint.route('/dashboard/words-cloud', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def textCloud():
    filterParams = buildFilterParams()
    productScopeStr = request.args.get('product') if request.args.get('product') else 'myproducts'
    multiWord = request.args.get('multiword')
    reviewsQuerySet = filterQuerySet(customer_id=session["customer_id"])
    wordsType = 'trending'

    if request.method == 'POST':
        wordsType = request.form['words-type']

    if wordsType and wordsType == 'topics':
        popularWords = []
        topics = topic.getSavedTopicsByQuerySet(reviewsQuerySet)
        topics = sorted(topics, key=lambda item: item['count'], reverse=True)
        for element in topics:
            item = {
                'topic': element['topic'],
                'driver': {
                    'totals': {
                        'reviewCount': element['count']
                    }
                }
            }
            popularWords.append(item)

        return render_template("text-cloud.html",
                               filterParams=filterParams,
                               wordsType=wordsType,
                               currentProduct=productScopeStr,
                               multiWord=multiWord,
                               topics=topics,
                               popularwords=popularWords)
    elif wordsType == 'trending':
        popularWords = topic.popularTopics(reviewsQuerySet=reviewsQuerySet)
        return render_template("text-cloud.html",
                               filterParams=filterParams,
                               wordsType=wordsType,
                               currentProduct=productScopeStr,
                               multiWord=multiWord,
                               topics=[],
                               popularwords=popularWords)
```

In the jinja template, I have a select box that has 2 options: trending and topics. I added an onChange event for select elements which makes a post request with the updated value. But every time I change the select value it displays only the first table. As you can see in my template I have two tables :

```
<i class="fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Talk About shows how many reviews talk about this subject
                {% if wordsType == 'trending' %}
                <table id="popular-words" class="table table-bordered tablesorter">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Topic</th>
                            <th>Talk About</th>
                            <th>Sentiment</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    {% for item in popularwords %}
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <a href="javascript: document.location = getFilteredReviewsURL({word:'{{ item.topic }}', shape:'suffix'}, page='/dashboard/word-explorer');">
                            {{ item.topic }}
                            </a>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {{ item.driver.totals.reviewCount }}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {{ item.driver.sentiment.tag }}
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                {% else %}
                <table id="popular-topics" class="table table-bordered tablesorter">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Topic</th>
                            <th>Frequency</th>
                            <th>Count</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    {% for topic in topics %}
                      <tr>
                        <td class="maxw-350">
                          {% for keyword in topic.keywords %}
                            <a href="javascript: document.location = getFilteredReviewsURL({search:'{{keyword}}'});">
                                {{ keyword }}
                            </a>
                          {% endfor %}
                        </td>
                        <td class="no-wrap">
                          {% if topic.frequency >= 2 %}
                            high
                          {% elif topic.frequency > 1 %}
                            medium
                          {% else %}
                            low
                          {% endif %}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                          {{ topic.count }}
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                  </tbody>
                </table>
                {% endif %}
```

Do you have any ideea why my table does not changes?